# Hondurean folklore name like "Sumadi" or "Sumati"?

Tags: myth-identification

A team of friends/colleagues from Honduras mentioned that they will name their project after a local legend, myth, or hero in Honduras / Central America.

They told me the name several times, but only verbally so I don't know how to spell it. I've spent a surprisingly long time searching for it online without being able to find anything.

I believe the phonetic spelling would be something like

> "Sumati"

or

> "Sumadi"

I found this online briefly once during a meeting, but can't find it again. I must be misspelling it. I'm starting to wonder if there's an 'r' in there...

**UPDATE**

Others should definitely add their answers with more info than what I found. It turned out that the name is

> Sumadi

I am still seeking contextual info about this name / legend. I will update this self-answer once I have more information.

So far, I've found that this is certainly a *unique* name, because:

> Out of 5,933,561 records in the U.S. Social Security Administration
>   public data, the first name Sumadi was not present. It is possible the
>   name you are searching has less than five occurrences per year.

An Internet search like "Sumadi Honduras" returns surprisingly little.

Comment: asking them for an email is not possible?

Comment: @Tom Possible, but not the most diplomatic approach perhaps. I wanted to do research on my own to be respectful and diligent.